# Form validation with ajax and laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm using ajax to submit my form. The issue I'm having is that if I have 2 or more errors that need to be displayed, I can't seem to get them to be displayed separately. The errors show up on 1 line.

This is my ajax code.

```
$('.ceromony_form').submit(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();          
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ceromony_post',
        type: "post",
        data: {'name':$('input[name=name]').val(), 
                'surname':$('input[name=surname]').val(), 
                'email':$('input[name=email]').val(), 
                'attendance':$('input[type=radio]:checked').val(), 
                'no_guest':$('input[name=no_guest]').val(), 
                'guests':$('textarea[name=guests]').val(), 
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
            },
            success:function(data){
                $(".success_wrapper").append('<div class="success">'+data.message+'</div>');
                $(".ceromony_form")[0].reset();
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                var errors = xhr.responseJSON;
                var test = [errors.name[0], errors.surname[0]];

                if(test){
                    $(".error_wrapper ul").html('<li class="error">'+test.join('\n')+'</li>');
                }
            }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a brake

```
 $(".error_wrapper ul").html('<li class="error">'+test.join('</br>')+'</li>');
```